# zsh tab completion for ssh using IP Address

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I ssh into several machines that are just IP Addresses, however I noticed a while back that tab completion stopped working when trying to SSH to them. I use zsh and I can tab complete a regular domain name with ssh, but all the IP machines that I use dont tab complete any more, did something break here? or whats the deal?

- OS X - 10.9.3
- zsh - 5.0.2

Comment: How does the first column (up to the first space; `awk '{print $1}' ~/.ssh/known_hosts`) of your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` look like? Are there hostnames and IP addresses (and maybe comma-separated lists of both) or do you have only hashes (probably starting with `|1|`)?

Comment: I have a list of hostnames and ip addresses. No hashes at all. The only odd one is [localhost]:2224

Comment: The "odd one" is the notation for non-standard ports (2224 instead of 22). It *should* not be responsible for the issue, I have those, too. To rule out problems with `known_hosts` you could try deleting all but one entry and see, if the behavior persists. (Don't forget to backup it beforehand :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you set the use-ip style?
`zstyle ':completion:*' use-ip true`
the documentation says that ip addresses are stripped from the host databases by default. use-ip allows completion of them.
http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-use_002dip_002c-completion-style

Answer (score 2):

Your ssh might be hashing the entries at known_hosts?

Best usability solution in general for ssh IMO is to create ssh host aliases, and then just use the alias in the command line. Eg. add something like this to you `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host foo
  # HostName also accepts numeric IP addresses
  HostName XXX.ZZZ.YYY.BBB
```

then you just use `scp backup.tar foo:`

Check `man ssh_config` for more info. From the manual:

```
 HashKnownHosts
         Indicates that ssh(1) should hash host names and addresses when they are added to ~/.ssh/known_hosts.  These hashed names
         may be used normally by ssh(1) and sshd(8), but they do not reveal identifying information should the file's contents be
         disclosed.  The default is “no”.  Note that existing names and addresses in known hosts files will not be converted auto‐
         matically, but may be manually hashed using ssh-keygen(1).  Use of this option may break facilities such as tab-comple‐
         tion that rely on being able to read unhashed host names from ~/.ssh/known_hosts.
```

Ok ignore the above, I see in a comment that that is not the case, will leave it there for reference though.

PS: you can always manually set the hosts to be completed by zsh using something along the lines of:

```
hosts=(foo.bar.com faa.bar.com fee.bar.com)
zstyle ':completion:*:hosts' hosts $hosts
```

Or do a much more complicated version of it, such as described here https://www.maze.io/2008/08/03/remote-tabcompletion-using-openssh-and-zsh/index.html

Comment: This does sort of solve my problem by making a shortcut to SSH to the IP. But doesn't solve the problem of why just IP addresses dont tab complete for ssh, but regular domain names do.

Comment: Did you check whether SSH is now encrypting the entries at `known_hosts`?

Comment: @Mentch ok, I saw in comments to the question you known_hosts is not hashed. Are you using oh-my-zsh? (an often source troubles like these). Note that oh-my-zsh has code mucking with ip-completion for ssh.

Comment: Yes I am using oh-my-zsh